# Setting Mouse Resolution at Startup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mouse, cinnamon

My mouse is way too fast, so I have to slow the Coordinate Transformation Matrix of the mouse down.  I can do it manually using xinput, and setting the appropriate prop. However, I run into issues when attempting to set it with a startup script.

In my home directory I wrote the script MouseResolution.SH
THe contents of the script are:

```
#!/bin/sh
xinput set-prop 8 145 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
xinput set-prop 9 145 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
```

It accesses and sets the coordinate Transformation Matrix properties for both listings of my mouse. (I'm guessing one is virtual.)

I then used chmod +x to make the script executable, and added it to the list of startup applications.

I'm running Ubuntu with the Cinnamon desktop, in case that matters.

Does anyone know why this script isn't being run after a reset?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. I had to remove the startup entry and re add it. I guess previously I added it to start up before running `chomd +x`